# Showing That a Certain Sequence of Random Variables is i.i.d.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on the following problem for my probability theory course.

> Let $U$ be a Uniform($[0,1]$) random variable (i.e., the distribution of $U$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$). Define $X_n=\lfloor 2^n U \rfloor, \ n= 1,2,\dots,$ to be the $n^{\text{th}}$ digit in the binary expansion of $U$
>   ($\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$). Show that $X_1, X_2, \dots $ are i.i.d. random variables.  Note i.i.d. stands for independent identically distributed.

So I am not really sure how to approach this problem. I know that if I can somehow show that for any $(x_1, x_2, \dots)\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ I have $P(X_1\leq x_1, X_2\leq x_2,\dots )= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X_i\leq x_i)$ then I will have shown they are independent.

When it comes to showing that they have identical distributions, I have no idea, mainly because I don't even understand what each $X_n$ is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hints: (1) Read up on what a binary expansion of a decimal is. (2) Try to show that $P(X_n=1|X_1...X_{n-1})=P(X_n=1),\;\forall n$

Comment: Could you remind me what $P(X_n=1|X_1\dots X_{n-1})$ is called, so I can look it up in my book to remind myself what it is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot a comma on either side of the ellipsis. It just means the probability that the $nth$ digit will be a 1 given that you know the values of the previous $n-1$ digits. Its defined as $\frac{P(X_1\cap X_2\cap...\cap X_{n})}{P(X_1\cap X_2\cap...\cap X_{n-1})}$

Comment: Maybe start by thinking about what you wrote: no, $X_n=\lfloor 2^n U \rfloor$ is not a digit in the binary expansion of $U$ (except if $n=1$).

Comment: @Bey Sorry but $\frac{P(X_1\cap X_2\cap...\cap X_{n})}{P(X_1\cap X_2\cap...\cap X_{n-1})}$ is plainly absurd (but $P(X_n=1|X_1,\dots,X_{n-1})$ is allright).

Comment: @Did can you clarify the absurd part? I was trying to rewrite the cond. prob in terms of something more elementary.

Comment: @Bey What would be $X_1\cap X_2$ for some random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$? Poor me is unable to give a meaning to it.

Comment: @Did perhaps it's informal notation that I've seen, but I always took it to mean the set of joint outcomes $(X_1,X_2)$...I wasn't going to go into $\sigma$-algebras to make this precise

Comment: @Bey If you can define precisely $P(X_1\cap X_2)$, please do so (but I am afraid that starting from $(X_1,X_2)$ being "the set of joint outcomes" is not going to lead you very far). Mentioning or not mentioning sigma-algebras is offtopic here since, once again, your $P(X_n=1\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})$ is precise and rigorous and correct and intuitive.

Comment: @Did $P(X_1\cap X_2)$ is not precise. Its a generic shorthand (albeit sloppy) reference to $P(X_1=x_1 \cap X_2=x_2)$ for some as yet unspecified $(x_1,x_2)$. I agree that conditional probability is the correct way to say it..I was attempting to get it to something simpler for the OP, who didn't understand the conditional notation. Obviously, this has been a bust!

Comment: @Bey I know--and I think it is a disservice to the authors of basic probability questions to use it. The site is full of questions by nonexperts lost in confusions between random variables, their distributions and the values they take.

Comment: @Did ok, point taken.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th place digit of a binary expansion can have only two values: $0$ or $1$.   It's binary.

$X_1$ $X_2$ are independent because, they are leading digits of the binary expansion of a uniform$[0.\dot{\overline {000}}_2;0.\dot{\overline {111}}_2]$ random variable):

$$\begin{align} \tfrac 1 {4_{10}} & = \mathsf P(0.00\dot 0_2\leq N < 0.00\dot 1_2) & = \mathsf P(X_1=0, X_2=0) \\ & = \mathsf P(0.01\dot 0_2\leq N < 0.01\dot 1_2)  & = \mathsf P(X_1=0, X_2=1)\\ & = \mathsf P(0.10\dot 0_2\leq N < 0.10\dot 1_2)  & = \mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=0)\\ & = \mathsf P(0.11\dot 0_2\leq N < 0.11\dot 1_2)  & = \mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=1)\end{align}$$

Hence $$(X_1, X_2) \sim\mathcal U \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$$

So can you verify that: $\mathsf P(X_1{=}x, X_2{=}y) = \mathsf P(X_1{=}x)\;\mathsf P(X_2{=}y)$ for all $(x, y) \in \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$

And does this trend continue ? ...

Comment: Graham Kemp, thanks for your help. In your answer I'm am unsure what some of your notation means. What does $[0.\dot{\overline {000}}_2;0.\dot{\overline {111}}_2]$ mean? Also I don't know what $\frac{1}{4_{10}}$ followed by the two columns of probabilities means. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The dot above the line means the digits beneath are repeated indefinitely. The subscript indicates the digital representation is base 2 or 10. $[x;y]$ is the real interval from $x$ to $y$ inclusive. In this case $[0.00\dot{\overline 0}_2;0.11\dot{\overline 1}_2]$ is the real interval between 0 to 1 in binary digit representation written specifically to indicate the range of the first two binary digits.